# Removing a custom tab in MS Word ribbon for MS Office

Tags: vba, ms-word, tabs, ms-office

I had a custom ribbon tab installed in MS Word (the tab works for MS Office 2007 and up).  I want to remove this tab, but I cannot determine how to do that.  I've looked through the "add a custom ribbon tab" answers and they did not help. I know the tab was created with VBA.  I do not have the code that created the tab, it was installed with some sort of installer file, which I do not possess.

Any ideas as to how I can remove this ribbon tab?  thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on the ribbon and select `Customize the Ribbon`
2. Find the name of the tab you want to remove on the right and uncheck it
3. Click OK

Comment: Sorry, I tried that. The tab does not show up in the Customize Ribbon lists.  You can see it on the ribbon itself, but no where in the options or menu items does it (or any of its buttons/menu items) appear.  Really weird.  That's why I haven't found a way to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by downloading the CustomUIEditor from here: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winfiles/OfficeCustomUIEditorSetup.zip

This allows you to edit the XML within your ribbon and remove the tab you don't want. Just make a backup of any files you edit as it's quite easy to break stuff